# using if and else if statements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a away (the correct and easy way) to use IF and else IF statements in javascript.

here is what I am trying to do...

at the moment, I am joining 2 input fields value and display them in another input balue like so:

```
function FillIn() {
  document.getElementById('custom').value = 

'Main Text:' + ' ' +  document.getElementById('inputName').value + ', ' + '1st Text:' + ' ' + document.getElementById('inputName101').value

    ; 
}
```

so basically the above code will place the values of `inputName` and `inputName101` into the `custom` input field. this works just fine.

Now, I have 2 radio buttons which I want to display their Values into the custom input field  depending on which one is selected/`checked`.

for this I am using the following code:

```
    function FillIn() {
      document.getElementById('custom').value = 

    'Main Text:' + ' ' +  document.getElementById('inputName').value + ', ' + '1st Text:' + ' ' + document.getElementById('inputName101').value

if(document.getElementById('male').checked) {

   + ', ' + 'Type:' + ' ' + document.getElementById('male').value

}else if(document.getElementById('female').checked) {

     + ', ' + 'Type:' + ' ' + document.getElementById('female').value

}

        ; 
    }
```

however, i am not sure if I am doing this correctly as I don't get the values of radio buttons in the `custom` input field at all..

Could someone please advise on this?

EDIT:

HTML for radio buttons:

```
<input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="Road Legal" onclick="showhidediv(this);">  

<input id="female" type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" value="Show Plate" onclick="showhidediv(this);">
```

Comment: can you share your HTML code for radio buttons?

Comment: Where are you calling fillin? And why is female "show plate" and male "road legal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work as it is... you can't just concatenate strings in and out of `if` statements as if it was a string. You need to do it like this...

```
function FillIn() {
  document.getElementById('custom').value = 'Main Text:' + ' ' +  
    document.getElementById('inputName').value + ', ' + '1st Text:' + ' ' + 
    document.getElementById('inputName101').value;

  if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
    document.getElementById('custom').value += ', ' + 'Type:' + ' ' +
      document.getElementById('male').value;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('female').checked) {
    document.getElementById('custom').value += ', ' + 'Type:' + ' ' + 
      document.getElementById('female').value;
  }
}
```

In fact, that most probably threw an error on console, you should check those to see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Agree, but the OP clearly lacks the knowledge to fully understand how this works. So making it elegant deffinitely has no use for him. Other than that, I assume you down-voted, do you actually think the answer is not useful? One thing is for it not be elegant, but it does work and it did answer the OP's question.

Comment: elegant or inelegant.. it answered my question so appreciate your help. I don't know why I have to write a code that is pretty or elegant as some call it when either way it works the same!

Comment: Because with that attitude you are certain to paint yourself into a corner with inelegant code that does not work for some reason

Comment: @mplungjan, what you just said holds no water. why? well, because the "inelegant" code as you called it works very well and it is fairly explanatory... if it works now then I don't see why it should just suddenly stop working in the future.

Comment: I re-formatted so it is less horrific and removed my downvote. I still strongly dislike the repeated code instead of using a var and the lack of ternary which is not rocket science. Let's agree to disagree and you will mark my words one day

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you're doing it wrong, you can't directly concatenate if / else conditions with strings, and the cleaner way to write your code would be

```
function FillIn() {
    var str = 'Main Text: ';
    str += document.getElementById('inputName').value;
    str += ', 1st Text: ';
    str += document.getElementById('inputName101').value;

    if ( document.getElementById('male').checked ) {
        str += ', Type: ';
        str += document.getElementById('male').value;
    } else if ( document.getElementById('female').checked ) {
        str += ', Type: ';
        str += document.getElementById('female').value;
    }

    document.getElementById('custom').value = str;
}
```

Comment: `var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender"); str += ', Type: '+(gender[0].checked)?gender[0].value:gender[1].value;`

Comment: @mplungjan - Indeed, a ternary in parenthesis can be concantenated, I did do that at first, but decided to write it really verbose to make a point; you don't have to make a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an `if` statement inside an expression. You have happened to write it in a way that actually runs, but the expressions inside the `if` statement are just evaluated and discarded.

You can use the conditional operator in an expression:

```
function FillIn() {
  document.getElementById('custom').value = 
    'Main Text:' + ' ' +  document.getElementById('inputName').value + ', ' +
    '1st Text:' + ' ' + document.getElementById('inputName101').value +
    (document.getElementById('male').checked ?
      ', ' + 'Type:' + ' ' + document.getElementById('male').value :
      (document.getElementById('female').checked ?
        ', ' + 'Type:' + ' ' + document.getElementById('female').value :
        ''
      )
    ); 
}
```

Using local variables for the elements makes the code a bit more readable:

```
function FillIn() {
  var male = document.getElementById('male');
  var female = document.getElementById('female');
  document.getElementById('custom').value = 
    'Main Text:' + ' ' +  document.getElementById('inputName').value + ', ' +
    '1st Text:' + ' ' + document.getElementById('inputName101').value +
    (male.checked ?
      ', ' + 'Type:' + ' ' + male.value :
      (female.checked ?
        ', ' + 'Type:' + ' ' + female.value :
        ''
      )
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Why not assign fillin to onclick and use "type "+ this.value?